# How would you send clock impulses to a camera with an Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega

Hardware newbie here and I need to know how to connect my TSL 1401 line scan camera to an Arduino Mega so that I can send it the needed impulses. The Mega has a hundred different sockets and the Schema just scared me when I looked at it.

I just want to know which socket I can connect to the CLK and SI ports of my camera so that I can get and an analog output of pixels.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a link to the datasheet of the TSL 1401 and the schema of the arduino mega that you are using.

Comment: Is this related to [this question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24840)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the camera that you're using but you send in impulse just sending digital write signal, waiting a little bit and then turning it off. You do this over and over again until you have all the pixels. Here is an example where I send 128 impulses:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
    delay(1);  
    digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
    delay(1);
  }
```

Depending on the hardware you are using you might have to send a SI (signal impulse) prior to the CLK impulses and the delay in between them will vary. The best thing to do is to read the documentation to find these figures.